How to pivot predictions over several timesteps against actual values?
I have a python script that produces predictions for a timeseries over several timesteps like this:

I would like to pivot or rearrange the predictions so that I have a new column named Predictions. In that column I have in sequential order Prediction_1, Prediction_2 etc. And then we have four columns time_from_actual_1, time_from_actual etc, that contain the prediction values. This way, for each row, we have a date, an actual value, a "Predictions" value that indicates the number of predictions, and then four values than show the four different timesteps in the predictions.
The output should look like this:

Here is what I've tried with sample data:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Create a DataFrame with daily values for 10 days
date_range = pd.date_range(start="2023-01-01", end="2023-01-10", freq='D')
actual_values = np.random.randint(90, 110, size=len(date_range))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_range, 'Actual': actual_values})

# Create prediction columns
prediction_period = 4  # 4 days for each prediction
predictions_df = df.copy()

for i in range(len(df)):
    prediction_dates = pd.date_range(start=df['Date'][i], periods=prediction_period, freq='D')
    predictions = np.random.randint(90, 110, size=prediction_period)

    # Add the predictions to the DataFrame
    for j, pred_date in enumerate(prediction_dates):
        pred_col_name = f'prediction_{i+1}'
        if pred_date in predictions_df['Date'].values:
            predictions_df.loc[predictions_df['Date'] == pred_date, pred_col_name] = predictions[j]

# Fill NaN values with empty strings
predictions_df = predictions_df.fillna('')

# Reshape the DataFrame
reshaped_data = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    prediction_name = f'prediction_{i+1}'
    if prediction_name in predictions_df.columns:
        for j in range(prediction_period):
            if i + j < len(predictions_df):
                reshaped_data.append({
                    'Date': predictions_df['Date'][i + j],
                    'Actual': predictions_df['Actual'][i + j],
                    'Prediction': prediction_name,
                    'time_from_actual_1': predictions_df.loc[i + j, prediction_name] if j == 0 else '',
                    'time_from_actual_2': predictions_df.loc[i + j, prediction_name] if j == 1 else '',
                    'time_from_actual_3': predictions_df.loc[i + j, prediction_name] if j == 2 else '',
                    'time_from_actual_4': predictions_df.loc[i + j, prediction_name] if j == 3 else '',
                })

reshaped_df = pd.DataFrame(reshaped_data)



Thank you for any suggestions!

Can you have NaNs in between some numbers? If yes, what should happen?

@mozway NaNs would not be an issue in my real world dataset. It would be an interesting challenge though. NaNs would also appear as NaNs at the corresponding timestep depending on the difference between the Actual date and the predicted value

You could reshape with melt, get rid of the empty rows, then assign the initial index per group and pivot+join:
cols = ['Date', 'Actual']

out = predictions_df[cols].join(predictions_df
 .filter(like='prediction_')
 .melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='Predictions')
 .replace({'value': {'': None}})
 .dropna(subset='value')
 .assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby('Predictions')['Predictions'].transform('idxmin'),
         col=lambda x: x.groupby('idx').cumcount().add(1)
        )
 .pivot(index=['idx', 'Predictions'], columns='col', values='value')
 .reset_index('Predictions').add_prefix('time_from_actual_')
)

Another approach by shifting the original non-empty data up per column and transposing. This relies on a range index in the original dataset.
cols = ['Date', 'Actual']

out = predictions_df[cols].join(predictions_df
 .filter(like='prediction_')
 .apply(lambda x: x[x.ne('').cummax() & x[::-1].ne('').cummax()]
                   .reset_index(drop=True))
 .rename(lambda x: f'time_from_actual_{x+1}')
 .T.rename_axis('Predictions').reset_index()
)

Output:
        Date  Actual time_from_actual_Predictions time_from_actual_1 time_from_actual_2 time_from_actual_3 time_from_actual_4
0 2023-01-01      96                 prediction_1               97.0               92.0               91.0              101.0
1 2023-01-02     109                 prediction_2               95.0               91.0               90.0              101.0
2 2023-01-03     104                 prediction_3              101.0              106.0               99.0              105.0
3 2023-01-04     100                 prediction_4              104.0              104.0              108.0              101.0
4 2023-01-05      97                 prediction_5              109.0               92.0               94.0              108.0
5 2023-01-06      96                 prediction_6               96.0               98.0               96.0              107.0
6 2023-01-07     108                 prediction_7               93.0              103.0              107.0               98.0
7 2023-01-08     100                 prediction_8               91.0              109.0              104.0                NaN
8 2023-01-09     100                 prediction_9              101.0               97.0                NaN                NaN
9 2023-01-10      93                prediction_10              103.0                NaN                NaN                NaN


One option would be to dump down into numpy, take advantage of np.diagonal, transpose and concat relevant parts to form a new dataframe. Note that this answer is specific to the shared dataframe; if you can vary the dataframe's height and columns, I could possibly adapt it to be more generic:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

predictions_only=predictions_df.filter(like='prediction')

columns=predictions_only.columns

numpy_array = (predictions_only
               # you can ignore this conversion
               # i did not want to lose the perf.
               # benefits of working with numbers in numpy
               .astype(str)
               .replace('',np.nan)
               .astype(float)
               .to_numpy()
               )

diagonals = [numpy_array.diagonal(-1*num) for num in range(4)]

max_length = max(map(len, diagonals))

new_arr=np.full(shape, fill_value=np.nan)

for num, array in enumerate(diagonals):
    new_arr[num,:array.size] = array

reshaped=pd.DataFrame(new_arr.T,columns=new_arr_columns)

new_arr_columns = [f'time_from_actual_{num}' for num in range(1,5)]

to_concat = [predictions_df.Date, predictions_df.Actual, 
             pd.Series(columns,name='Predictions'), reshaped]

pd.concat(to_concat,axis=1)

        Date  Actual    Predictions  time_from_actual_1  time_from_actual_2  time_from_actual_3  time_from_actual_4
0 2023-01-01      96   prediction_1                97.0                92.0                91.0               101.0
1 2023-01-02     109   prediction_2                95.0                91.0                90.0               101.0
2 2023-01-03     104   prediction_3               101.0               106.0                99.0               105.0
3 2023-01-04     100   prediction_4               104.0               104.0               108.0               101.0
4 2023-01-05      97   prediction_5               109.0                92.0                94.0               108.0
5 2023-01-06      96   prediction_6                96.0                98.0                96.0               107.0
6 2023-01-07     108   prediction_7                93.0               103.0               107.0                98.0
7 2023-01-08     100   prediction_8                91.0               109.0               104.0                 NaN
8 2023-01-09     100   prediction_9               101.0                97.0                 NaN                 NaN
9 2023-01-10      93  prediction_10               103.0                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN


use the function df.pivot after fill NaN values with empty strings
predictions_df = predictions_df.fillna('')


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Smaller  DataFrame for demo
data = {
    'Date': pd.date_range(start="1990-01-01", end="1990-01-04", freq='D'),
    'Actual': [100, 105, 110, 115]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
'''
        Date  Actual
0 1990-01-01     100
1 1990-01-02     105
2 1990-01-03     110
3 1990-01-04     115
'''
# Define the prediction period
prediction_period = 2

# Create an array of actual values
actual_values_array = df['Actual'].values

# Get the number of rows
num_rows = len(df)

# Create a matrix to hold the predictions
prediction_matrix = np.full((num_rows, prediction_period), np.nan)

# Create row indices and column offsets
row_indices = np.arange(num_rows)
column_offsets = np.arange(1, prediction_period + 1)

# Use broadcasting to calculate indices for shifted values
shifted_indices = row_indices[:, None] + column_offsets

# Create a mask for valid indices
valid_indices_mask = shifted_indices < num_rows

# Assign actual values to the prediction matrix using valid indices
prediction_matrix[valid_indices_mask] = actual_values_array[shifted_indices[valid_indices_mask]]

# Add prediction columns to the original DataFrame
pred_cols = [f'time_from_actual_{i}' for i in range(1, prediction_period + 1)]
df[pred_cols] = prediction_matrix

df['Predictions'] = [f'prediction_{i+1}' for i in range(len(df))]

print(df)
'''
     Date       Actual  time_from_actual_1 time_from_actual_2  Predictions
0 1990-01-01     100           105.0             110.0     prediction_1
1 1990-01-02     105           110.0             115.0     prediction_2
2 1990-01-03     110           115.0             NaN       prediction_3
3 1990-01-04     115           NaN               NaN       prediction_4

'''

